Django Form - POST method not recognised as POST in views
In my django project, I am trying to create a form which the user will access through a specific url.
By clicking on the url, the user will be automatically redirected to a pager_id.
Inbetween the user click on said url and being redirected to page_id, a form will be passed in the background, without any template.
Slight problem, the form does not pass the if request.method == "POST":.
I know that because the print rendered in the console is this is not a post request.
I think its probably the first time Im not using a template to render the form.
I would normally specify something like:
<form "method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
</form>

But I am not doing this, this time. Everything is handled in the view.
Question:
Assuming this what is causing problem: Does Django require to use a template to render the form? Or is there a way to specify method="POST" in a different way? Or is there something else I am not seeing?
views.py
   def function(request, page_id):
            form = myform(request.POST)
            if request.method == "POST":
                print('this is a post request')    
                if form.is_valid():
                    data = form.save(commit=False)
                    ...
                    data.save()
                    return redirect('page', page_id=page_id)
            else:
                form = myform()
                print('this is not a post request') #<-- this is what gets printed in the console
        else:
            print('Come back later!')
    
    return redirect('page', page_id=page_id) 


This should resolve the issue :-
   <form method="POST">
   {% csrf_token %}
   </form>


I may have misguided you in my message. I am not using any template and therefore <form method="POST"> is not in use. I reworded my initial message.
